# is there any skype api available to integrate with salesforce [skypedeveloper]

Tags: salesforce, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

we wanted customize our salesforce application via giving the skype conference link while sending the email from the application itself. the application is completely on visualforce pages and controller so i dont see any appexchange app will help on this.

I have already checked the below links though i could not get any integration apis
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/onlinemeetinginvitation_ref
https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no integration Apis as of now.  Only you have to write your own integration logic using `Skype for Web SDK`. It is a bit complicated SDK and not properly documented or maintained. It has tight coupling with Azure AD and video streaming doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox.

Some integration use cases/examples can be found [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/T698)

Other relevant information.

https://dev.skype.com/

https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/tree/master/Skype